# Keras vgg16 fine tuning using generator flow_from_dataframe val_acc frozen at 0

Tags: python, keras

I have been trying to train a regression model to predict the quality of the inferred images and always my val_accurracy is frozen at 0 and does not change at all

Here is my model:

```
training_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale= 1./255)
val_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale= 1./255)

train_generator = training_gen.flow_from_dataframe( 
    dataframe = df_train,
    x_col = 'dist_img',
    y_col='dmos',
    target_size = (384, 512),
    batch_size = 64,
    class_mode = 'raw'
)

test_generator = val_gen.flow_from_dataframe( 
    dataframe = df_test,
    x_col = 'dist_img',
    y_col='dmos',
    target_size = (384, 512),
    class_mode = 'raw',
    batch_size = 64
)
pre_trained = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_tensor = Input(shape=(384, 512, 3)))
for layer in pre_trained.layers[:15]:
    layer.trainable = False
for layer in pre_trained.layers[15:]:
    layer.trainable = True

last_layer = pre_trained.get_layer('block5_pool')
last_output = last_layer.output
 
x = GlobalMaxPooling2D()(last_output)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
predictions = Dense(1)(x)
```

Comment: Accuracy is a classification metric, you cannot use it in regression.

Comment: Thanks Dr Snoopy. It works well now